# TPOTClassifier producing errors

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I was trying to use  [TPOTClassifier](https://rhiever.github.io/tpot/using/) on [Forest Cover Type Prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction).
But after initial run, its producing errors as output. It will be helpful if
you suggest how to resolve the error. Thank you.

```
from tpot import TPOTClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# loading the data
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
data_test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
data.head()
data_test.head()

print data['Cover_Type'].values
data1 = data

data1= data1.rename(columns={'Cover_Type':'class'})
data1.dtypes

features =list(data1.dtypes[1:55].index)
target =list(data1.dtypes[55:56].index)
print data1.dtypes.tail()

## train test split
X_train , X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data1[features],data1[target],train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)
X_train.head()

tpot =TPOTClassifier(generations=5, population_size=500, verbosity=2)       
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print (tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
tpot.export('tpot_forest_pipeline.py')
```

But its producing errors:

Generation 1 - Current best internal CV score: inf

Generation 2 - Current best internal CV score: inf

Generation 3 - Current best internal CV score: inf

Generation 4 - Current best internal CV score: inf

Generation 5 - Current best internal CV score: inf

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

1 tpot =TPOTClassifier(generations=5, population_size=500, verbosity=2)

2 tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)

3 print (tpot.score(X_test, y_test))

4 tpot.export('tpot_forest_pipeline.py'

355 if not self._optimized_pipeline:

356 raise ValueError(There was an error in the TPOT optimization

357 process. This could be because the data was
358 not formatted properly, or because data for)ValueError: There was an error in the TPOT optimization process.This could be because the data was not formatted properly,or because data for a regression problem was provided to the TPOTClassifier object.Please make sure you passed the data to TPOT correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the data1[features], which should be a 1-D array but pandas dataframe is 2D array-like data structure. Change the tpot.fit() codes as below will solve the input issue.

```
tpot.fit(pd.np.array(X_train), pd.np.array(y_train).ravel())
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have made the changes as you suggested. It displayed the generations. Then it displayed                                                                                                          Best pipeline: ExtraTreesClassifier(SelectFromModel(input_matrix, 1.0000000000000001e-05, 60, 0.080000000000000002), 6, 0.63)                         After that, there is an error while exporting  to tpot.export('tpot_forest_pipeline.py')

Comment: How can I decipher the parameters from Best pipeline display ? How to resolve the error coming at the end while exporting  through                                            tpot.export('tpot_forest_pipeline.py')